# Counterexample: A bundle map which is not a pullback

Tags: examples-counterexamples, vector-bundles

I'm trying to find a morphism of vector bundles (aka. bundle map) that is not a pullback, preferably with compact base spaces. I'm pretty sure, I saw such example once, but I can't reconstruct it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:
$\require{AMScd}$

No such counterexample exists. We will take as our definition of bundle map the following.

A bundle map $f$ between bundles $p \colon E \to B$ and $p' \colon E' \to B'$ is a continuous function $f \colon E \to E'$ which restricts to an isomorphism on each fiber. This then induces a map on the base spaces $\bar{f} \colon B \to B'$ making the diagram 
\begin{CD}
E@>{f}>> E';\\
@VpVV @Vp'VV \\
B@>{\bar{f}}>> B'
\end{CD}
commute.

Now we claim that $p \colon E \to B$ is isomorphic to $\bar{f}^* E' \to B$. 
Recall that the total space $\bar{f}^*E'$ takes the form
$\bar{f}^*E' = \{(b,e'\} \in B \times E' \mid \bar{f}(b)=p'(e')\}$.
Consider the map
\begin{align*}
g \colon E &\to \bar{f}^* E'\\
e &\mapsto (p(e),f(e)).
\end{align*}
We claim this map $g$ is a continuous function which maps each fiber isomorphically onto the corresponding fiber (over the same base space $B$), hence must be a homeomorphism, and so $E$ was in fact the pullback of $\bar{f}$ to begin with.

Failed Counterexample Before Edit:

Let's take the trivial vector bundle over a point 
$\mathbb{R} \to *$
and a non-trivial bundle, say the mobius band bundle $M \to S^1$. We of course have a map of spaces $S^1 \to *$, but is this map covered by a bundle map? I believe it is. So once we have a bundle map from the mobius band bundle to the trivial bundle it can't be a pullback since then this would imply the mobius band bundle is trivial.

Comment: I'm afraid this is not extendable to a bundle map. Imagine you start at the fiber over $x\in S^1$ and "walk" around the circle once, then you would have to map the fiber upside down.

Comment: I worried about this too, however all we need is the restriction of the map on the total spaces to each fiber to be linear. What if we take the map on the total spaces to be the zero map, sending every point in the mobius band to zero? This is linear on each fiber, and still covers $S^1 \to *$.

Comment: Oh, then our definitions of bundle map differ. I read the map has to be non-singular on each fiber. In particular, a bundle map is always between bundles of the same dimension.

Comment: I have edited my answer to reflect this definition. Let me know if you have any questions about this proof.

Comment: This doesn't explain why I thought I had seen such counterexample, but it perfectly answers the question. Thank you!